# Why search a linked list?

Tags: algorithm, list, data-structures

I am reading "The Algorithm Design Manual" and it says that the three operations on a basic List are *searching*, *insertion* and *deletion*. Then it goes on to describe an algorithm in C which, once it finds the node it is looking for (by comparing the data of the nodes with that searched) it returns that node (and, thereby, any nodes connected underneath it). If it doesn't find what it's looking for, it returns `NULL`.

So my question is if we know what we are looking for why do we search for it? And if the reason is just to see if it is included in the list, then why isn't a boolean function "contains" what we really want?

Comment: I imagine searching includes using an arbitrary searching predicate. ie find the first value in a list which satisfies a certain criteria. Equality is only one possible predicate.

Comment: How would a `contains` function work, if not by searching the list?

Comment: @arootbeer it would absolutely need to search the list, however, its intent is different. "Search" returns the node we are looking for or `null` whereas `contains` would simple say whether the data in question is in the list.

Comment: From your own words: "the three operations on a **basic** List are...".  There are several answers relating to what one might do with the actual node one was looking for, but a `contains` function is by definition an extension of a `search` function, and therefore `search` would be included where `contains` might not be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A node may contain more information than just the value you are search for. Imagine a list that models a file system. You search for a file by name, but the node you get back could contain the file name, the file size, the last time it was modified, the file's owner, access permissions, and other data.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, one searches for a node to do something with it. Perhaps you would like to set a new value into an existing node, delete everything after the node, or insert something after that node. If you maintain a certain order in your list, semantics of your searching function may be expanded to look for the first item greater than a certain value, et cetera.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, you need that specific node for some operation. Remember, the node itself and its content are two different logical entities.

Answer (score 0):

A boolean function "contains" may be all we want. What if we want to search for some data set that we don't have but we do have an identification number though?

Try to look at examples in textbooks as general examples. Searching for a boolean and searching for a record based on some other value are both performing the same operation, just with different outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a simple example...

You write a program that asks people for their age (in years) and stores them in a list and then shows a histogram (how many people there have been of every age) or maybe it shows how many people have turned 21 in the past year.

In such a program you may not know in advance what is going to end up on the list. And that's why you search it.

Answer (score 0):

The only entry into a linked list structure is the `head` node. To get to a particular node in the list you have to iterate through `head` node to the next node, to the next node, ... and finally to the target node, hence the searching. So `contains` would do exactly the same - search for a node which `equals` to the node you're looking for.